# Why the restricting URI characters in the config file?

Tags: security, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am using clean URL for search. If the user types a single quote it says disallowed URI character. And I know how to enable a character for appearing in the URL. I want to know the security vulnerabilities on allowing certain characters like braces, quotes and others?

I want to know this by any means like explanation or external references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about "query string" part of the URL, if that is so then your framework is probably disallowing those characters to prevent SQL inject sort of attacks as in your code you may end up using those query string values to construct a SQL query and boom, your application is SQL injected.

Comment: He's talking about the non-query_string part of the url. The query string is actually not affected by the character restriction in Codeigniter. Input like that should be cleaned anyways, so I'm not sure this would be the only reason they would suggest the restriction.

Comment: +1 Because this is a good example, but it still seems like a good developer shouldn't require the restriction. From their words: "[restriction exists] in order to help *minimize* the possibility that malicious data can be passed to your application"

Comment: The time i encountered the problem was when i added a single quote. Will url encoding the clean url prevents throwing that exception in CI?

Comment: @Jayapal url encoding should be not trigger the error and is a good idea anyways.